# EF 6, Update Entity from DTO, but only existing properties (generic code)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, dto

I'd like to know the best way to update an Entity retrieved from the DB.
The front-end requests an update for an entity, sending a DTO which contains the id of the entity, and also some fields.
Then with this Id, I look for the entity in the DB, and here comes the question:

I want to update the fields of the entity which are set in the DTO, and keep the other fields.
Obviously I can do it explicitly, field by field, but I'd like to know a best practise to do it in a generic way for all the properties of the DTO.

The code would look like:

```
[HttpPut]
public IActionResult Put([FromBody]PersonDTO pDTO) {
   Person p = GetPersonById(pDTo.IdPerson);
   p.Name = pDTO.Name;
   p.Address = pDTO.Address;
   // and 100 more fields
   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

How can I avoid the mapping between the DTO and the Model? I though about using reflection, but i can't find out if there is a better, more elegant, and standard way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most popular choice in c# when it comes to mapping objects is to use AutoMapper, http://automapper.org/

```
Person person = Mapper.Map<Person>(pDTO);
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I map like this, then I have 2 instances of" Person":
1) The one you show
2) The one retrieved from the DB (since the pDTO is a subset of fields of Person)

Comment: then you should use  ```Person p = GetPersonById(pDTo.IdPerson); 
    Mapper.Map(pDTO, p);```

Comment: @AdamStawarek your last comment was the answer in my case. Thank you!